# Error in image warping code

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

point=np.zeros((32,2),np.float32)
point2=np.zeros((32,2),np.float32)
count=0

def click(event, x, y, flags, param):  
    global count
    global x1,x2,y1,y2

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if count%2==0:
            point[count,0] = x
            point[count,1] = y
            print (x,y)
            x1=x
            y1=y
            count+=1

        else:
            point2[count,0] = x
            point2[count,1] = y
            print (x,y)
            x2=x
            y2=y
            count+=1
            mophing()

def mophing():

    height,width,channel = img.shape

    for y in range (height):
        for x in range (1,width):
            if(x<x1):
                xratio=x/x1
            else:
                xratio=(width-x)/(width-x1)

            dx=int((xratio)*(x2-x1))
            img[x,y]=img[x+dx,y]

    #Result      
    cv2.imshow('change', img)

img = cv2.imread('messigray.png')

cv2.namedWindow('original')  
cv2.setMouseCallback('original', click )
cv2.imshow('original', img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

It's my Python code
I check point1 and point2 in someones example picture using mouseEvent,
I would like to Warping between the two clicked pointers.
Then I wrote a program that changes the value of X tab only.
However, when you run this code, the results at the bottom are printed.

```
77 96
374 290
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\open7\Desktop\MouseWarping.py", line 28, in click
    mophing()
  File "C:\Users\open7\Desktop\MouseWarping.py", line 42, in mophing
    img[x,y]=img[x+dx,y]
IndexError: index 480 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 480
```

Among the result, The above two values are coordinates of the two clicked points
I would like to know the problem and solution to the last line code.
And I would like to know whether this code is a NumPy issue or OpenCV problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured this out by now, but I believe your issue was a simple 0-based vs 1-based error. Python indexes start at zero, but your `range` starts at 1. You could modify your `range` call to start at 0, but this will mess up your math. Instead, just subtract 1 when accessing your `img` array:

```
        img[x-1,y-1]=img[x-1+dx,y-1]
```